# Code Map for ASP.NET Projects in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-map

I need to visualize complex business logic on a single ASP.NET page that has over thousands of lines code so I decided to give Visual Studio's own "Code Map" feature a shot, which is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx

The tool looks like this:

[image: Code map working example]

I tried with VB.NET and C# (including MVC) projects and it was working very well... or that's what I thought, until I tried to use code map tool on an ASP.NET project.

[image: Code map button example]

Instead I got this helpful window:

[image: Empty code map window]

I couldn't find any documentation that says "it's not supported" so I guess I'm doing something wrong? Is there any way to get this tool work, manually trying to add did not help either. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to show? A class or a `cshtml` file?

Comment: I tried to show solution, asp.net project itself and individual .vb and .cs files; everyone of them gave me an empty window. I even tried .aspx files. It seems that Code Map skips entire asp.net project for me, it _doesn't_ even show code map for single, concrete classes in the App_Code folder. It _does_ show me the code map of other projects in the same solution, but not ASP.NET.

Comment: Are you using one of those [File System Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e5x4xz73(v=vs.100).aspx)? Because afaik they're not really supported in VS2012 and later (click "other versions" in the documentation)

Comment: You're correct! It works correctly with asp.net application project. This was one of the legacy projects. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @ta.speot.is forgot to add reply notification, please see my previous comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're using a File System Web Site Project. These have nebulous support in Visual Studio 2012 and later. I say "nebulous" because I haven't found anything that explicitly states they're deprecated, but [the documentation for them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e5x4xz73(v=vs.100).aspx) is only provided for Visual Studio 2005, 2008 and 2010.

If you need Code Map support for your project, consider [converting it to a Web Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx).